# php registration class wire up with front end form?

Tags: javascript, php, oracle, api

Using oracle server 11g.

My front end is only 4 input boxes. I have some javascript validation as well but it's working fine so i won't post it, mainly having problems with how my classes interact with the form elements.

I'm assuming I still need to do all the php validation with the server. I'm a bit confused on how all this interacts with my form elements.

Here's my html form:

```
<form id='register' action='register.php' onsubmit="return validateForm()" method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset>
<legend><br/>Create An Account</legend><br/>
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<label for='username' >Username*: </label>
<input type='text' name='username' id='username' maxlength="50" /><br/><br/>
<label for='email' >Email Address*:</label>
<input type='text' name='email' id='email' maxlength="50" /><br/><br/>
<label for="password">Password*:</label>  
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required><br/><br/>
<label for="password">Confirm Password*:</label>  
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required><br/><br/>
<label for='cpassword' >&zwnj;</label>
<input type="hidden" name="fsubmitted" value="TRUE"><input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Register' />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is my class and some methods:

```
class Shopper extends Base {

protected $shopper_id;
protected $email;
protected $user_name;
protected $temp_token;
protected $sign_in_token;

protected $UserShoppingList;

function __construct($email = null) {

    if (strpos($email, '@') === false) {
        $this->sign_in_token = $email;
    } else {
        $this->email = $email;
    }
}


public function activate($temp_token) {
    global $db;

    $this->set_temp_token($temp_token);

    $vars = array();
    $vars[] = array(':i_temp_token', $this->get_temp_token());


    return $db->get_function_as_proc('custom.japi_shopper_identity.Activate_User(:i_temp_token)', $vars) == 'Y';
}

public function create($password) {
        global $db;

        if (!$this->get_email() || !$this->get_username()) {
            return false;
        }

        $vars = array();
        $vars[] = array(':email', $this->get_email());
        $vars[] = array(':username', $this->get_username());
        $vars[] = array(':password', $password);

        $id = $db->get_function_as_proc('custom.japi_shopper_identity.create_user(:email, :username,  :password)', $vars);
        $this->set_id($id);

        // If it failed, it'll puke on the procedure. If we've come this far, we
        // know it worked.
        return true;
    }

public function request_activation() {
        global $db;

        $vars = array();
        $vars[] = array(':i_shopper_id', $this->get_id());

        // Returns a temp token
        $temp_token = $db->get_function_as_proc('custom.japi_shopper_identity.activate_user_request(:i_shopper_id)', $vars);

        if ($temp_token == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $this->send_activation_email();
            return $temp_token;
        }
    }

public function set_email($email) {
        return $this->email = $email;
    }

 public function set_username($username) {
        return $this->user_name = $username;
    }
```

When I hit the register button what code should i have in action="register.php"?

Should i be able to keep all my code on one page?

And just instantiate the class Shopper?

```
$shopper = new Shopper();
$shopper->set_email($new_username.'@example.com');
$shopper->set_username($new_username);
$shopper->create('password');
$token = $shopper->request_activation();
```

and than hopefully the `request_activation` function will send them the e-mail for them to click the activate link?? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Additionally, I should be aware of empty stings on my php side of validation.

I'm assuming this should be fine?

```
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
      $error = array(); //Declare An Array to store any error message
      if (empty($_POST['name'])) { //if no name has been supplied
          $error[] = 'Please Enter a name '; //add to array "error"
      } else {
          $name = $_POST['name']; //else assign it a variable
      }

      if (empty($_POST['e-mail'])) {
          $error[] = 'Please Enter your Email ';
      } else {

          if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/",
              $_POST['e-mail'])) {
              //regular expression for email validation
              $Email = $_POST['e-mail'];
          } else {
              $error[] = 'Your EMail Address is invalid  ';
          }

    }
if (empty($_POST['Password'])) {
          $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Password ';
      } else {
          $Password = $_POST['Password'];
      }
}
```

Is there anything else I should be worried about?

Comment: any reason why `Shopper` does not have a name attribute?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go down the [Model–view–controller (MVC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) path I would recommend creating a controller class to handle the shopper.

This allows you to encapsulate the logic for handling resources in your app. And is a fair deal easier to handle than a bunch of nested ifs.

```
/**
* This class handles creating, showing and destroying shoppers
*/ 
class ShopperController {

    function newAction($shopper = null) {
        // render the form
        include "/views/shopper/signup.php"
    }

    function createAction($params) {
        $shopper = new Shopper($params);

        //@todo create validate method
        if ($shopper->validate()) {
            //@todo persist to database
        }
        else {
           // validation failed re-render form with values submitted 
           return $this->newAction($shopper); 
        }

        //Render some sort of response
        include "/views/shopper/show.php"
    }
    // ... more methods 
}
```

In register.php:

```
$controller = new ShopperController();

switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    case 'GET':
        $controller->newAction();
    case 'POST':
        $controller->createAction($_POST);
}
```

I don´t however really recommend writing a MVC framework from scratch if you want to get the job done.